# How to find out what is starting Hyper-V on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v

I wish to run a 64-bit VM in VirtualBox on Windows 10, so I need to disable Hyper-V.

I have tried various approachs (see the info below), but Hyper-V is still starting.

In my System Log (Admin Tools -> Events Viewer -> Windows Logs -> System) I see a message “Hypervisor successfully started” from the “Hyper-V-Hypervisor source, and it always occurs immediately after the “The firmware reported boot metrics” message from the Kernel-Boot source.

Is there some way of tracking down what process is starting Hyper V?

**Steps taken to disable Hyper-V**

- Disabled Hyper-V in “Window Features”
- Followed suggestions [here](https://forums.virtualbox.orgiviewtopic.php?f=25&t=99390): , specifically:

  - Disabled Device Guard in Computer Group Policy
  - Ran command “bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off”
  - Ran command “DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V”
- Followed suggestions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/virtualization-apps-not-work-with-hyper-v) to disable Credentials Guard
- Followed suggestions [here](https://petri.com/how-to-disable-hyper-v-completely-in-windows-10) to disable Secure Boot

Comment: In Windows Features, is Hypervisor Platform or Virtual Machine Platform running?

Comment: Do you have WSL2 installed?

Comment: Vbox and Hyper-V work together now.  Are you up to date on both Windows and VBox?

Comment: WSL2 is not installed

Yes, Vbox and Hyper-V are both up to date (new machine, fresh install)

Hypervisor platform is off; I don't think Virtual Machine Platform is running (I can't find anything related to it on the system)